# Restrict string creating object every time

Tags: java

I am working on a method where I need complete folder path like /abc/xyz/mln/ for which I am using recurring method call as below sample code:

```
public String getFolderDetails(String userid, Long folderId) 
            {
        String folderName = "";
        String folderPath = "";

        try {
                folderName = documentFilesName.getString("name");
                parentFolderId= documentFilesName.getLong("parentFolderId");
                if(documentFilesName.has("parentFolderId"));
                {

                    if(parentFolderId.exist)
                    {
                        folderPath = folderPath+"/"+folderName;
                        getFolderDetails(userid, parentFolderId);
                    }

                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return folderPath;
    }
```

but every time  folderName and folderPath gets assigned to "" due to recurring it doesn't keep/append the folderName and everytime new value gets assigned to folderPath.

Whats the better approach I can use here? same is happening with StringBuffer/Builder it create new object always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide the `folderName` and `folderPath` variables as parameters to your method, thus this: `public String getFolderDetails(String userid, Long folderId)` becomes this: `public String getFolderDetails(String userid, Long folderId, String folderName, String folderPath)`.

For the first method call, you would provide the empty string variables and then, when you do the recursive call just do `getFolderDetails(userid, parentFolderId, folderName, folderPath);`

Alternatively, you could have an external `StringBuilder` which gets populates within the method itself, thus this line: `folderPath = folderPath+"/"+folderName;` would look something like `stringBuilder.append("/").append(folderName);`.

Comment: thanks :), it sound good and simple solution but again after "return folderPath;"  cursor comes to "getFolderDetails(userid, parentFolderId);" how we can stop that?

Comment: @nilFi: Please update your question to show what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

```
public String getFolderDetails(String userid, Long folderId) {
  // This will be the start of recursion so initializing foldername and folderpath with blank 
  getFolderDetails(userid, folderId, new StringBuilder(""), new StringBuilder(""));
}

// recursive method takes two extra parameters for path and name
private String getFolderDetails(String userid, Long folderId, StringBuilder foldername, StringBuilder folderpath) {
    /// Then each time you dont create a new builder just append to it
}
```

You need to pass the state i.e. `StringBuilder`s to the recursive method so that it can keep appending to it.

```
folderpath.append(File.separator).append(folderName);
```

You should not use `'/'` as hard coded while using path, as it is file system dependent, rather you should use `File.separator` for that as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

You can always avoid recursion by using a stack (LinkedList)

```
LinkedList<File> stack = new LinkedList<>();
stack.add(root);

while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
    File current = stack.removeFirst();

    ...
    if (someCondition) {
        stack.addLast(someChildFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems interesting but I am bit confused here and unable to understand how it can work.